# Count time between 2 dates for multiple forms using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where every user is able to set time  for many in a dynamic form.

 Clicking on `Add field button` the user can add a range of time and on the right of time pickers will appear the difference of these 2 times. Also i have a default time: `12:08 - 12:10`, so the default range should be `0 hours and 2minutes`, but this value is saved just for the first input, but when i click on `Add field` button, i  don't see the calculated range.

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState({ 0: "12:08" });
  const [fullDate2, setFullDate2] = useState({ 0: "12:10" });
  console.log(date, fullDate2);
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values, date);
  };

  const changeDate1 = (momentDate, dateString, key) => {
    console.log(dateString, key);
    setDate({ ...date, [key + 1]: dateString });
  };
  const changeDate2 = (momentDate, dateString, key) => {
    setFullDate2({ ...fullDate2, [key + 1]: dateString });
  };

  const myDiff = (startSubEventTimes, endSubEventTimes, k) => {
    if (Object.keys(endSubEventTimes).length) {
      const startTime = moment(startSubEventTimes[k], "HH:mm");
      const endTime = moment(endSubEventTimes[k], "HH:mm");
      const duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
      const hours = parseInt(duration.asHours(), 0);
      const minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes(), 0) - hours * 60;
      if (!isNaN(hours) && !isNaN(minutes)) {
        return `${hours}hours and  ${minutes}minutes`;
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <TimePicker
                    defaultValue={moment("12:08", "HH:mm")}
                    format={"HH:mm"}
                    // value={date}
                    onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                      changeDate1(date, dateString, field.key)
                    }
                  />
                  <TimePicker
                    defaultValue={moment("12:10", "HH:mm")}
                    // value={fullDate2}
                    format={"HH:mm"}
                    onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                      changeDate2(date, dateString, field.key)
                    }
                  />
                  <span>
                    difference -{" "}
                    {Object.keys(fullDate2).length
                      ? myDiff(date, fullDate2, field.key)
                      : 0}
                  </span>
                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Question: How to set default range for every generated form?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-bird-6mlfs?file=/index.js:313-3735

Comment: Your form is a mix of controlled data, and uncontrolled data. It gets messy, when you mixing them. Always try to decide what you want to going for. (I would recommend the controlled way, but its up to you).
Your controlled fields where fields working from a `state`. Your uncontrolled fields where your values not stored directly in the state, instead of `antd` makes some magic with your data. So my question: What data flow would you goes by?

Comment: @Asking let's discuss in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217550/antd-timepicker-component

Answer (score 0):

You should define a default value for a new keys:

```
  const myDiff = (startSubEventTimes, endSubEventTimes, k) => {
    // if (Object.keys(endSubEventTimes).length) {
      const startTime = moment(startSubEventTimes[k] || "12:08", "HH:mm");
      const endTime = moment(endSubEventTimes[k] || "12:10", "HH:mm");
      const duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
      const hours = parseInt(duration.asHours(), 0);
      const minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes(), 0) - hours * 60;
      if (!isNaN(hours) && !isNaN(minutes)) {
        return `${hours}hours and  ${minutes}minutes`;
      }
    // }
  };
```

If you remove a field, also should remove the [key] values from the state, to prevent next default values memorizations.

But to update it correctly check the answer by @Rostyslav

But I still would send it to a code review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have made a comment for my `-` on your post. Can you also explain it on this answer?

Comment: The problem was here `but when i click on Add field button, i don't see the calculated range.`. I have fixed the problem and provided the solution and you stole my answer 19 mins later...

Comment: Not correct. I has also figured that `key`issue out (Okay I could just point to your answer). But your answer was not related to the question: `Question: How to set default range for every generated form?`

Comment: Okay, have updated the answer, to prevent any kind of duplication

Answer (score 0):

Add change handlers to your add field button

```
   <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  changeDate1()
                  changeDate2()
                  }}
                  block
                >
```

Update the change handler so that if no values are passed the default dateString is set to "00:00".
If key is also undefined, which is the case when you click the add field button, it will be computed as the length.

```
const changeDate1 = (momentDate, dateString="00:00", key) => {
    console.log('changedate1', dateString, key);
    key = key !== undefined ? key : Object.keys(date).length
    setDate({ ...date, [key]: dateString });
  };
  const changeDate2 = (momentDate, dateString="01:00", key) => {
    key = key !== undefined ? key : Object.keys(fullDate2).length

    setFullDate2({ ...fullDate2, [key]: dateString });
  };
```

Last step is to remove defaultValue prop and add value prop for TimePicker

```
<TimePicker
                    value={moment(date[field.key], format)}
                    format={format}
                    onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                      changeDate1(date, dateString, field.key)
                    }
                  />
                  <TimePicker
                    value={moment(fullDate2[field.key],format)}
                    format={format}
                    onChange={(date, dateString) =>
                      changeDate2(date, dateString, field.key)
                    }
                  />
```

Removing a row might interfere with how we're setting default keys in the change handler. To avoid property collision you can find the max prop instead of length.
The maxKey expression checks to see if date has length, since calling max on an empty object will result in `infinity` when we want `0` instead.

```
const changeDate1 = (momentDate, dateString="00:00", key) => {
    console.log('changedate1', dateString, key);
    let maxKey = Object.keys(date).length ? Math.max(...Object.keys(date)) + 1 : 0
    key = key !== undefined ? key : maxKey
    setDate({ ...date, [key]: dateString });
  };
```